# При каких условиях можно задавать для (* , html, body) display flex? И стоит ли это делать?

Tags: html, css, frontend, flexbox

При каких условиях можно задавать для (* , html, body) `display: flex`? И стоит ли это делать?
Так как хочется делать максимально гибко все.
Благодарю.

Comment: Для * точно не стоит.

Comment: Что вам даст `display: flex` для `* , html, body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну html стилизовать так себе идея. Если задача требует того, чтобы у боди был flex, то почему нет. В спецификации это не запрещено) Да и валидно это)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)

Comment: не за что , поставь галку что вопрос закрыт.)